# String replace for randomly changing data

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace between 2 characters which are randomly changing.

For example: I am trying to replace font family randomly from `{font-family: 'Arial'}` to body `{font-family: 'verdena'}`. But every time I replace one font family i cannot find out which family type to replace as it is changing randomly.

Please help me in finding solution for replacing random string in between two strings.

```
//Generate Random Font
var FontNames = new List<string> { "Georgia", "Serif", "verdana", "arial", "calibri" };
Random randonGenf = new Random();
int index = randonGenf.Next(FontNames.Count);
var FontName = FontNames[index];
FontNames.RemoveAt(index);

var fileFontContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\SchoolSite\default.css");
fileContents = fileFontContents.Replace("body {font-family: 'Arial'}", "body {font-family: '" + FontName + "'}");
```

Comment: how about instead of changing the styles assigned to an element, you just assign a random class to the element?  Then you don't have to do weird string replacement.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It seems a bit weird to be regex-replacing CSS from C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) for this. For example:

```
fileContents = Regex.Replace(
    fileFontContents,
    @"body \{font-family: '[^']+'\}",
    "body {font-family: '" + FontName + "'}");
```

If you want to do it without the quotes, it would be:

```
fileContents = Regex.Replace(
    fileFontContents,
    @"body \{font-family: [^\}]+\}",
    "body {font-family: " + FontName + "}");
```

In a nutshell, the `'[^']+'` says, "match a single quote, then any sequence of characters that is not a single quote, and finally another single quote. So that matches `'anything'`.

In the non-quote case, I use the closing brace as a delimiter. That is, `[^}]+\}` says: "match any sequence of characters that isn't a closing brace, and follow it with a closing brace."

Note that these regular expressions are quick and dirty. They expect valid input, and will fail spectacularly if the input is malformed.

Comment: Jim,  can I handle this regular expression if we have to show without single quotes?

I tried this way and it didnot work

fileContents = Regex.Replace(
    fileFontContents,
    @"body \{font-family: [^']+\}",
    "body {font-family: " + FontName + "}");

Comment: @"body \{font-family: [^}]+}" this trows error [] unterminated set. Could you please check your updated answer with out single quotes.